# Is immediately initializing a variable important in C++

Tags: c++, variables, memory, initialization, undefined-behavior

I've recently read a programming book. It says that if we don't give a value when initializing the variable like in the example given below:

```c
int i;
int i {0};
```

... then it might result in runtime errors sometimes. However, I'm not sure if this is correct. Will an uninitialized variable be set as a random integer? Why might this cause a runtime error?

I haven't experienced this kind of runtime error yet. Is it important to give the init value to a variable?

Comment: it might under some debug environments, it might not under others, its undefined behaviour so anything could happen

Comment: C++'s axiom is "Do not pay for whay you do not use". So it will not initialize variables for you unless you ask for it. (because there is times when initialization takes time even when you don't need it).

Comment: Is it important? Not on its own, no. It has better performance in many cases, and it avoids a whole lot of problems later on. Both of which is... kind of important. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In C++, non-static variables in function scope (inside of functions, also known as local variables), or class member variables without any other initialization, doesn't get initialized by default. They will have an *indeterminate* value. Using an indeterminate value in any way leads to *undefined behavior*.

Unless you're using uninitialized pointers, it's unlikely that you will get a crash (though some floating-point values could lead to exceptions). Plain integers will just give you unexpected results.

With all this said, you don't *have* to explicitly initialize all your local variables, if you plan on assigning values to them later (but before you use their values).

---

Variables defined outside of functions or classes will be value initialized. Which sets their values to zero (or the corresponding value for the type, i.e. pointers become null pointers).

`static` local and member variables will also be value initialized.

Comment: They *are* initialized, but they are *default initialized*, which leaves their value indeterminate. If they weren't initialized at all, it would also be UB to assign them later. This is because assignment only changes the value of an object, but it doesn't begin the lifetime of an object (except for union members).

Answer (score 0):

Yes the book was right. It is a common recommendation to always initialize variables as soon as you declare them. The reason is that reading from an uninitialized variable invokes undefined behavior.

This code

```
 int evil;
 std::cout << evil;
```

Might look ok in a debug build. In a debug build the compiler does more than it needs. It might do the initialization for you. Though, in a debug build the compiler also does less then in a release build: It does not apply optimizations. It does not analyze your code and transform it for better performance, as it would in a release build. Thats why the above code can appear fine in a debug build while in a release build bad things can happen.

Suppose you know that you are not allowed to read from an uninitialized variable and you write:

```
 int ok;
 ok = 42;
 std::cout << ok;
```

Then all is fine. However, usually code doesnt look that simple. It rather looks like this:

```
 int notok;
 if (some_condition) {
     notok = 42;
 } else {
     std::cout << "hello world";
 }
 std::cout << notok;
```

It is easy to accidentally use a variable that has not been initialized. Hence the recommendation to always initialize them:

```
 int good = 42;
```

Comment: `ok` is not uninitialized. It is *default initialized*. Its lifetime has begun (which is why it's okay to assign it later), but its value is indeterminate.

Comment: @JanSchultke in language-lawyer terminology you are right. Colloquially imho it is fine to call it uninitiliazed. The fact that it gets initialized and is indetermine is a quirk of C++ initialization. Note that even the coreguideline says "before initialized" even though formally it is initialized https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-initialize

Comment: @JanSchultke sometimes its a tightrope act to explain to a beginner without making to bad simplifications. Imho this one is okish, ymmv

Comment: I think it's necessary to at least add a footnote with clarifications when simplifying to the point of being incorrect. And it's not much harder to explain it in terms of *"indeterminate value"* or *"garbage value"* than in terms of *"uninitialized"*.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response above. I wrote some code and run tests in different optimize level in my computer(linux 6.2.0-24-generic). The result was given below:

```bash
❯ g++ varinit.cpp -o varinito3 -O3
 g++ varinit.cpp -o varinito2 -O2
 g++ varinit.cpp -o varinito1 -O1
 g++ varinit.cpp -o varinito0 -O0
❯ ./varinito3
0
❯ ./varinito2
0
❯ ./varinito1
0
❯ ./varinito0
32766
❯ icpx varinit.cpp
❯ ./a.out
-1884400440
```

I notice that in optimized build (G++) int variable will be default initialized as zero, but in no optimize compile, the default value is random constant (will not change by time when you run it). In addition, in intel cpp compiler(icpx) the value is random but changes each time you compile it.

Comment: is this an answer to the question?